# Apple Music play songs in order

Tags: apple-music

I listen to Apple Music (subscription), and when I play an album I can't find a way to play the songs in order.

If I have an album pulled up and tap the first song, it plays and when done skips to a random song on the album.

If I click the ellipses and hit ...

[image]

and then the (what appears to be) "play album" button, it still randomizes...

[image]

Is there a way to make songs on an album play in order?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.  I tried to find another answer, but missed that one!  This question should probably be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

you can add it to playlist,(playlist on bottom(in homepage))
you can see your own picture(second picture) says add to playlist.
[image: playlist on bottom(in homepage)]